# Intermittent 500 Response from Server for API Call in Angular and Spring Boot Deployment on Tomcat"

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, server, tomcat9

I have Angular and Spring Boot deployed on same tomcat server and when I hit a specific API, I get 500 response from server and when I again hit the same, it gets loaded. What maybe the possible error here?

I have Angular and Spring Boot deployed on same tomcat server and when I hit a specific API, I get 500 response from server and when I again hit the same, it gets loaded. Expected output is the API must perform the same way first time as it is behaving the second time.

Comment: You need to check the server log. 500 response means some thing gone wrong at the server side which can be any thing.

Comment: @seenukarthi error is not logged in the log of springboot